# Traversing and modifying a tree-like list of dict structure

Tags: python

I have a structure that looks like this:

```
[ {'id': 4, 'children': None},
  {'id': 2, 'children': 
    [ {'id': 1, 'children':
        [ {'id': 6, 'children': None},
          {'id': 5, 'children': None} ]
      },
      {'id': 7, 'children':
        [ {'id': 3, 'children': None} ]
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

I also have a list of selected IDs, `[4, 5, 6, 7]`.  I want to traverse the list and for each object in the list, add a `selected` key with a value of `1` if it is selected, and `0` if it is not.

Currently I am doing this recursively with this function:

```
def mark_selected(tree, selected):
    for obj in tree:
        obj['selected'] = 1 if obj['id'] in selected else 0
        if obj['children'] is not None:
            obj['children'] = mark_selected(obj['children'], selected)
    return tree
```

This seems to work fine, but I was wondering if there was a more clever way to do this, possibly using list comprehension or generators.

Can anyone come up with a more elegant solution for this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Recursion is perfectly elegant. List comprehensions don't apply as you're altering the structure in place, rather than producing a new sequence. As for generators, you could write a DFS or BFS traverser.

```
def dfs(nodes):
    if nodes is not None:
        for node in nodes:
            yield node
            yield from dfs(node['children'])

for node in dfs(tree):
    node['selected'] = node['id'] in selected
```

Python 3.3 and later can use the recursive yield above (`yield from` syntax). Earlier versions would instead loop over the recursive results, yielding those:

```
def dfs(nodes):
    if nodes is not None:
        for node in nodes:
            yield node
            for child in dfs(node['children']):
                yield child
```

If the list of IDs to select is large, it would be more performant to convert it from a list to a set, which will speed up lookup (the `node['id'] in selected`).

```
selected = set(selected)
```

Answer (score 2):

Since you operate by modifying the input object, and since objects have reference semantics in Python, you don't need to return a value or use the return value in the recursive step. Also, if you can replace the 'None' entries for children with '[]' (better yet, use tuples throughout rather than lists), then you can simplify the logic - you don't need a base case at all, then, because you can recurse to an "empty tree", and it will just run the for-loop for all zero items, i.e. do nothing - which is what you want.

And FFS, why aren't you using Python's built-in boolean type?

```
def mark_selected(tree, selected):
    for obj in tree:
        obj['selected'] = obj['id'] in selected
        mark_selected(obj['children'], selected)
```

(Oh, and do you even need to keep the children in a particular order? Having a list of dicts which all contain an 'id' key is unnatural; it makes more sense to have a dict where the keys are the ids, and the values are dicts without the 'id'.)

Comment: Thanks for the advice.  I am not using boolean type because this will be converted to JSON and interact with another language that wants `0` and `1`.

Comment: Ah. You can still do it more simply, though: `int(obj['id'] in selected)`. :)

Answer (score 2):

I like to use closures for recursive functions, for this example it doesn't matter much, but you can save the need to pass 'selected' in the recursive call. In more complex examples you can keep a fair bit of state in the containing function for use by the recursion.

```
def mark_selected(tree, selected):
    def recur(tree):
        for obj in tree:
                obj['selected'] = 1 if obj['id'] in selected else 0
                if obj['children'] is not None:
                    recur(obj['children'])
    recur(tree)
```