# "Flat is better than nested" - for data as well as code?

Tags: python, theory

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4372073/traversing-and-modifying-a-tree-like-list-of-dict-structure/4372174#4372174) question got me thinking: should we apply the principle that "flat is better than nested" to data as well as to code? Even when there is a "logical tree structure" to the data?

In this case, I suppose it would mean representing children as a list of IDs, rather than an actual list of children, with all the nodes in a single list:

```
[ {'id': 4, 'children': ()},
  {'id': 2, 'children': (1, 7)},
  {'id': 1, 'children': (6, 5)},
  {'id': 6, 'children': ()},
  {'id': 5, 'children': ()},
  {'id': 7, 'children': (3,)},
  {'id': 3, 'children': ()} ]
```

(I used tuples because I prefer not to give myself the flexibility to mutate an object until that flexibility proves itself to be useful and usable in a clear manner. In any case I would never use `None` here instead of an empty sequence, because it complicates the logic, and "special cases aren't special enough" - here, it isn't special at all.)

Certainly this is shorter, but the tree structure is obscured. Does that contradict "explicit is better than implicit"?

Personally I find that "flat is better than nested" is of limited applicability, and nowhere near the most important aspect of the Zen. (Certainly I could not do a lot of the nice functional-programming things that I do if I didn't allow myself significant nesting.) I suspect that the problem with "nested" is that it requires context switching when you comprehend the information. I really think this is more of a problem when following imperative logic than for parsing data or functional-style code - where it's easier to just mentally name the nested block, and consider its workings separately from the outer context.

What say you?

Comment: Good question, as the asker of the question you linked I am curious as well.  I would prefer not to obscure the tree structure but what you have in your post would certainly simplify the approach for performing an operation on each node in the tree.  Looking forward to seeing what others think.

Comment: I think you have to bear in mind the context that aphorism was made in. Python allows a certain degree of functional programming, but ambivalently (for instance destructive operations don't return values, closures are subtly broken, etc.) I don't think it would even occur to most people who mainly do pure functional programming to prescriptively say that flat is better than nested. If what I am operating on is a tree, I would rather see it represented as a tree.

Comment: Terrible question.  Conflating data with source code is like comparing an island and the Empire State Building.  Yes, the building is located on an island, but that's the only relationship they have.

Comment: Not a terrible question at all. It's good to think laterally. And asking questions is rarely terrible. He is asking, not telling, after all. :)

Comment: ... OTOH, nesting feels like a big mistake if you later realize that you need a **graph** structure. :) I've been playing devil's advocate for the flat structure here largely because my gut reaction to the question was "nested, hands down; I don't even really like the principle applied to code all that much, although I understand what it's trying to accomplish". ;)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I wouldn't inherently prefer either, but rather use whatever seems best suited to the task.

If the structure is important, nesting makes life simple. If you're regularly operating over each node, the flat structure makes it easy to use `for node in tree`. Of course, if you define your own class, its easy enough to abstract it so both options are simple; but it may be harder to use with external systems, such as converting to JSON.

Answer (score 13):

This is a completely subjective question.  The answer is, "it depends."

It depends on the primary use of your data.  If you continually have to reference the nested structure, then it makes sense to represent it that way.  And if you never reference the flat representation except when building the nested structure, then why have the flat structure at all?

The "flat" representation is one of the basics of the relational database model:  each type of data exists in a table just for that type, and any relationships among the items are contained in separate tables.  It's a useful abstraction, but at times difficult to work with in code.  On the other hand, processing all the data of a particular type is trivial.

Consider, for example, if I wanted to find all the descendants of the record with id 2 in your example data.  If the data is already in the hierarchy (i.e. native representation is the "nested" structure), then it's trivial to locate record id 2 and then traverse its children, children's children, etc.

But if the native representation is sequential as you've shown it then I have to pass through the entire data set to create the hierarchical structure and *then* find record 2 and its children.

So, as I said, "it depends."

Comment: Yeah, actually when I saw that example I was instantly reminded of the typical "org tree" example that many books on relational databases include. There's a time for that sort of organization, certainly. But there are also times when it can become really painful.

Comment: +1 - It's very subjective, I for one find a flat tree far, far easier to read than a heavily nested one. Don't ask me why.

Comment: Finding "all descendants of record X" with flat data is not as hard as you make it sound. You just find the node itself in the flat data (which should be fast because `id` should be a primary key, or rather, I should have organized the data like `{id: {rest of node}}` instead of `[{node}]` :) ) and build the hierarchical structure **of that subtree** - on demand.

Comment: +1 for pointing out the database connection. This is how databases store tree-like things. If you are going to serialize the tree, storing it flat can be helpful. Some such structures have ordering conventions, e.g. that all immed. children of a given node must be contiguous, or that a node must be immediately followed by all the subtrees below it -- so that traversing the list in order represents a known tree traversal. As a general comment I'd recommend hiding the entire tree inside a class, so you can encapsulate all the access methods.

Answer (score 10):

> should we apply the principle that "flat is better than nested" to data as well as to code?

No.

> Even when there is a "logical tree structure" to the data?

That's what "flat is better than nested" doesn't apply to data.  Only to code.

> ... the tree structure is obscured. Does that contradict "explicit is better than implicit"?

It's not even comparable.  The "flat tree" is a common SQL implementation because SQL can't handle indefinite recursion of a proper tree.

Comparing the Zen of Python (the language) with data structure design is nonsensical.  The two are no more comparable than than the number "2" and splitting a brick of cheese into "2" pieces.  One's a thing, the other's an action.

Data structures are things.

Python describes actions.

Comment: On the other hand, code is a type of data with a structure and syntax, for a particular purpose. Some programming problems can be implemented entirely in code, or in smaller amounts of code with look-up tables (e.g. state machines). So I think it's not so silly to compare code and data.

Comment: @Craig McQueen: While true, it's not helpful.  Both code and data are just sequences of bytes.  In which case, we can analyze them as long, complex numeric values, also.  Not very helpful.

Comment: But the structure of your data tends to determine the structure of your code. Declaratively nested structures tend to lead to nested code, though whether the nesting happens lexically or at run-time is a language detail. And this is part of what Karl was getting at, I think- when you program functionally nesting is a natural consequence of the paradigm. But Python is not a functional programming language. I tend to nest more in Python than most Pythonistas, but I do so less than I do in functional languages. Python is not CL, and it is not Haskell. Python's idiom is not functional.

Comment: I'm a heretic in a few ways; to be honest, I think Perl had it mostly right with the TIMTOWDI motto - although some ways are clearly better than others, and I haven't used Perl in years. :) But I do think that Python naturally lends itself to multi-paradigm programming, and I think that many people underestimate the power, in general, of mixing (impure) functional code with other styles. I'm not actually convinced that nested data leads to nested code all that often. When I write Python I often create complex nested expressions, but I nest the imperative constructs relatively little.

Comment: (con't) I find that Python's syntax simply makes those expressions surprisingly **readable**. Comprehensions are a truly beautiful thing; far easier for me to parse than the corresponding `map`/`filter` combination. I'm also rather happy with how the `x if y else z` construct turned out syntactically.

Comment: I'd agree that Python is a nice multi-paradigm language as long as the paradigms we're talking about don't include functional programming. Python is (intentionally?) pretty hostile to the functional style. I do a lot of impure functional programming in Python and.. it hurts. Either the designers of Python really don't want you to program functionally in Python, or they don't understand functional programming.

Comment: @T Duncan Smith: "Declaratively nested structures tend to lead to nested code."  Not really.  The run-time stack may be nested, but the functions and classes can be very flat.  The module that contains them can be flat.  And you don't need a hellishly complex package hierarchy to simply have a collection of flat functions.  The run-time nesting of the call frames has nothing to do with the Python language presentation of the source.

Comment: Well this is an extension of the original question. When Tim Peters said that flat is better than nested he didn't specify what he was talking about. If we are talking only about lexical nesting of functions and classes then I think the question is not important enough to comment on in the first place. But I suspect the intended meaning was deeper. In that case the trade-offs become more complicated.

Comment: @T Duncan Smith: The poem is about the language -- the Zen of Python.  It's not the Zen of Design or the Zen of Architecture or the Zen of Software.  I agree: "the question is not important enough to comment on in the first place".  A more focused question on how to represent tree structures is equally useless since the alternatives are well-known.  The "flat" tree structure is commonly used for SQL because of the limitations of the relational database.  None of this is very interesting.

Comment: @S. Lott: If Peters meant to restrict his koan to lexical nesting of functions, classes, modules, etc. it would be nice if he wrote some commentary on it sometime (Zen masters often do write commentary on koans, believe it or not.) Of course it would be nicer if people learned to trust their instincts (and maybe get burned if they are wrong and refine their instincts thereby.) Flat is better than nested, except when it isn't. I just wrote a function nested in a function nested in a function (though I expect I will refactor that away.) Here is the finger- here is the moon ;).

Comment: @T Duncan Smith: since we're on the tangent - I too do a lot of impure FP in Python and I don't find that it hurts at all. I just stop before the point where I would have to do something "abusive" in order to keep "being functional". But Python's syntax makes me **want** to write more of the code with basic FP idioms and concepts, whereas just looking at typical Haskell programs scares me away. I really think FP works better in combination with other idioms than it does on its own (never mind whether the FP part of the code has side effects; this is about overall expressiveness.)

Comment: BTW my understanding is that it's GvR specifically who's hostile to FP in Python in general, and that others had to work around him to get things like `reduce` into the built-ins at all.

Comment: FP is a prime example where the source syntax is flat (lots of functions) but the call stack becomes very convoluted.  The data structure may be deeply nested, also.  This is a prime example of "flat is better than nested" at the source level -- which is what the Zen of Python is about.  The call stack and data structure are not what's being talked about.

Comment: @T Duncan Smith: My understanding is Zen masters wrote commentaries on koans they were handed through tradition.    Programming is no different.  There's a wealth of tradition, some has value, some doesn't.  The Methodists say that you should use tradition, scripture, reason and experience.  What's important here is that the Zen of Python is about Python.  Not software in general.

Comment: Actually zen masters really changed interpretations a lot. It's hard to know for sure, what they meant, but I translate medieval Japanese to English as a hobby...

Comment: @T Duncan Smith: My knowledge of Zen is limited to a few decades studying karate -- clearly not as deep as your experience actually reading and understanding the original Japanese.  (I can barely count to 10 in Japanese.) The best I can do is lift up John Wesley's advice that tradition, scripture, reason and experience are all guides.  In this case, reason and experience are the basis for my claim that the Zen of Python could only apply to the language, not software engineering in general.

Comment: Well, who can understand Zen? And how? The truth might be that it is easier to understand Zen if you can't read the texts. Frankly I don't claim to understand it at all. But I know that it changed a lot over time. I think ;). But I think it might be a mistake to be dogmatic about Zen itself. I am almost sure that it is better to not make a lighthearted post Tim Peters made many years ago dogma when what we are dealing with is programming rather than Zen.

Comment: @T Duncan Smith: "dogma"?  Sorry.  Just trying to clarify a distinction that is pretty clear.  Code != data.  It doesn't seem like dogma to me.  But, if it's dogma to you, I apologize.  I've always found it a helpful distinction that code is active and data is passive.  But I guess that's a false duality and unhelpful even when a programming language seems designed around that duality.

Comment: Is 'flat better than nested' should be always applied to code? I think only when we talk about such things as conditions and loops but when we talk about classes (mainly about nested objects) it shouldn't be true permanently. Sometimes small nested objects are power because of flexibility rather then big flat classes with huge number of methods.

Answer (score 6):

"Everything should be made as simple as possible, but not simpler." Flat is simpler than nested. If you're dealing with data with *relevant* nesting, then flattening it probably violates the "but not simpler" part. I took the Zen of Python instead to be encouraging you not to complicate your life with nesting you don't really need, like an XML config file where a simpler flat format might suffice.

Answer (score 4):

This question can't be answered "in general" - there is no right answer.

For this particular example, I actually like the tree structure better.  Without knowing anything about the original application, and just looking at the structure, the relationship between the items is obvious.  With the flat structure, I have to read some documentation, or application code to "know" that your tuple of children refer to id's.

The tree structure is self-documenting - the flat structure isn't.

Comment: The question was actually partly motivated by reflection upon some work I did at a previous job, where I wrote something that required configuration data with a tree structure. A co-worker complained that it was harder to get the brackets right and/or visualise the nesting, or something, when you actually nest the data. But for files with a large number of "nodes", it becomes difficult to match up the IDs and see what's going on, too.

Comment: There's often not a "right" answer in programming...although often there are *wrong* answers!

Answer (score 3):

> Does that contradict "explicit is
>   better than implicit"?

Yes, particularly when being explicit prevents you from implicitly shooting yourself in the foot. The "tree" in your example can have multiple parents claiming to own the same children. It can also have multiple root nodes (and it does: 2 is a root node; 4 is a root as well as a leaf node.)

Comment: The data accurately corresponds to the original. I would argue that data can have a "logical tree structure" without all being in **one** tree :) Regardless, you make a good point.

Comment: True enough. But if you refer to it as "a" tree, then you're not seeing the forest for the "tree". :-)