# Flat is better than nested: how to deal with deeply nested dictionaries?

Tags: python, python-3.x

In my work as an engineer (not software) sometimes I have to program in Python. Following the tutorials, I learned about dictionaries and how they are used to store data, they are fast etc.

I have nested dictionaries that go to a level as far as 7 like so:

```
mydict['level1']['level2']['level3']['level4']['level5']['level6']['level7']
```

I have these little monsters because I parsed a document with a library that returns something like:

```py
components['comp1']['comp_name']
components['comp1']['comp_dimension']
components['comp1']['subcomponents']['subcomp1']
components['comp1']['subcomponents']['subcomp1']['comp_name1']
etc.
```

I have other dicts that are deeply nested too.

The problem I'm facing is that I need to iterate up to the last level to get and filter results since I don't know the keys beforehand, so I iterate like the following pseudo-code:

### Example 1: the pretty one

```py
filter_subcomps = ["comp1", "comp10"]
filter_value = 10.0

for component in components
    comp_name = components[component]['comp_name']
    comp_dimension = components[component]['comp_dimension']
    if components[component].get('subcomponents', False):
        subcomp_keys = filter_subcomps if filter_subcomps else components[component]['subcomponents'].keys()
        for subcomponent in subcomp_keys:
            etc etc
            if value > X:
                return value
```

### Example 2: a little bit uglier (going down 3 levels, still 4 to go...):

```py
# I changed the variable names and cut somethings to give a shorter example. 
# So there probably are some errors that you should ignore. 
# The goal is to show the ugliness of my code :)

    def get_peak_xy_position(self):
        peak_final_lst = list()
        x_coord_list = list()
        y_coord_list = list()

        filter_comp = self.params['options']['filter_comp']
        filter_comp_parent = self.params['options']['comp_parent']
        filter_peak = self.params['options']['filter_peak']

        for xy_coord in self.xy:
            peak_xy_list = [0]
            x_coord = float(xy_coord.split('_')[0])
            y_coord = float(xy_coord.split('_')[1])

            if self.components.get(xy_coord, False):
                comp_keys = filter_comp if filter_comp else self.components[xy_coord].keys()
                for comp in comp_keys:
                    if self.components[xy_coord].get(comp, False):
                        if self.components[xy_coord][comp].get('comp_parents', False):
                            comp_parent_keys = filter_comp_parent if filter_comp_parent else self.components[xy_coord][comp]['comp_parents'].keys()
                            for parent in comp_parent_keys:
                                if self.components[xy_coord][comp]['comp_parents'][parent].get('comp_signal', False):
                                    peak_signal = self.components[xy_coord][comp]['comp_parents'][parent]['comp_signal']['peak']
                                    final_peak = current_peak_signal
                                    if filter_peak:
                                        final_peak = current_peak_signal if filter_peak <= current_peak_signal else 0
                                    peak_xy_list.append(final_current)
            peak_final_lst.append(max(peak_final_lst))
            x_coord_list.append(x_coord)
            y_coord_list.append(y_coord)

        return x_coord_list, y_coord_list, peak_final_list
```

These are a fairly simple examples, sometimes the code goes to more than 10 levels of indentation which looks terrible and I have to scroll the page horizontally. Besides that, it's hard even for me to read the code after several days or weeks.

I read some tutorials from people that converts tabulated data to nested dicts and vice-versa and even people using xpath to access dict keys.

Anyway, **following the zen of python I'm certainly not respecting "flat is better than nested" since my code goes to astronomic levels of indentation.**

I was thinking to convert all the nested dicts to SQLite and query using SQL language instead of these ugly for loops and if conditions. So, what should I do? How do I deal with nested dicts in Python and at the same time keep the code as flat as possible? I'm a little bit lost here.

PS: my question has no relation to [“Flat is better than nested” - for data as well as code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4372229/flat-is-better-than-nested-for-data-as-well-as-code) since I already have deeply nested dicts. I want to know how to deal with these dicts, query / filter values etc. and at the same time have a flat code.

Comment: Sidenote: if you do `for component in components.values()`, you can replace `components[component]` with `component`. And `dict.get()` returns `None` by default, so no need for the `False` argument.

Comment: I know, I just wanted to emphasize the ugliness. :) Thanks for the comment.

Comment: If the nested dicts have greatly different structures, then use 7 separate functions which each call the next to get at the data. If the dicts are identical, then a recursive function might work.

Comment: The structures are related to each other (parent / child). I don't see how this will help to avoid the nested for loops, if conditions etc. In the example I filtered only one value, but imagine to filter more than one in different levels of keys. It's a mess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There exist several approaches to the problem:

1. Flatten the structure. If you presume that processing of the flat table will work faster, it might make sense to flatten your structure into the plain list of class or struct instances, and then process the plain list.
2. If the structure is uniform across levels (even if the names are different on each level), you can use simple recursion. You would have the function which will check if the item on certain level has children, and call itself with each of those children if they are present, or call the data processing function for the final level entries. If subcomponent names differ, you can have an array of such names that would say "on level 1 the items are called 'comp*', on level 2 - 'subcomp*' and so on.
3. If levels require completely different handling, introduce separate functions for each level.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I'm thinking to flat the dict, but then I don't see the point of nested dicts. That's why I'm confused. How to have a flat code with a nonflat data structure. Your approach number 3 does not comply with the 'flat is better than nested' statement the way I see, since I have to use several for loop to access sublevels and call the functions. I may be wrong. This problem seems like a paradox :) I think the approach number 2 doesn't work for my data, it's not that uniform.

Comment: @rafael If you don't have a flat data structure, flattening it will require the same approaches 2 or 3, just not to process the data but to extract them into the flat list. So of course you won't be able to avoid traversing the trees. The question is whether it is handy to process the data during traversing, or just to collect these data into the plain list. I don't know for sure but it's possible that there exist python libraries which will do this for you (flatten the tree).

Comment: Yes, there are some libraries. I'm taking a look at this one: https://github.com/ianlini/flatten-dict

Answer (score 5):

I would not change the data structure. If that's what you get and it models the problem well, so be it.

Split up your code in small little functions that take levels deeper down the structure.

```py
def filter_components(components, keys, value):
    # if key is not needed, use .values()
    for key, component in components.items():
        if 'subcomponents' in component:
            filter_subcomponent(component['subcomponents'], keys, value)


def filter_subcomponents(subcomps, keys, values):
    for subcomp in subcombs.values():
        # do stuff
```

Split more if it's more complicated.
Small, easily readable functions that do part of the work.

Comment: And the `filter_subcomponents` will call another filter subcomponents with other keys? I will try to give a more nasty example. the one I gave is very simple.

Comment: If that's what you need, yes. Split it up until the functions are small enough to be understood.

Comment: It seems very slow compared to query an SQL db, no? Not complaining, just trying to understand.

Comment: Slow? It should not really be slower than not splitting it in function,  the overhead is not that large. And if you have nested structures in an sqldb, also the query will get very large with lots of joins,  so I don't really see what you mean with comparing it to an SQL db

Comment: I wouldn't use nested structure in SQL, I would put everything in a table for one dict (flat), so it would use more space, but the query would be faster I think. Please take a look at the example 2.

Comment: Ok, now I'm confused. Is your problem representable by a flat structure without hierarchy? Than it would be for sure better to just flatten on the boundaries to your code. But if the problem has a hierarchy, choose a data structure that best represents that. Nested dicts is a very natural representation for that.

Comment: I get the nested dicts from parsing a file, there's no flat option, so if I want to flat my dict, I have to do it separately. But that's not quite the question. The question is how to deal with deeply nested dicts and at the same time have a flat code if possible.

Comment: Than the answer stands, split the logic in small independent function receiving well defined I puts and mutating or better returning modified values

Comment: I understand, but I still have to use at least 6 inner for loops right? Just to be sure.

Comment: Somewhere, these loops will exist. Depending on the concrete case, you might be able to write concise code using recursion.  But that would only hide the loop from plain sight

Comment: Splitting the logic into smaller functions simply exchanges in-function nesting for call-graph nesting, and may be cumbersome because of the need to pass local context between functions. Real flattening is all about elegant use of non-structured control-flow operators, such as `break`, `continue`, mid-function `return`, `with`, `raise`, &c. And of course, code-flatting seems quite hard without the good old `goto` statement, absent in _Python_. How, for example, would you translate into _Python_ [this]-(https://pastebin.com/raw/JzfwNBYJ) flat function in C#.