# Accessing a child node using its sibling key value pair in a nested map

Tags: java, json

I have a complex struct which is nested like shown below. I am trying to access the value of a nested key with its sibling's key:value pair.

Eg: My complex structure is:

```
 {

    key1:value,

     key2:

         [

         {a:1,c:{d:1}},

         {a:2,c:{d:0}}, 

        {a:3,c:{d:1}}

         ]

     }
```

I am trying to return the value of d where a:3. Clearly d is a's sibling's child. If I traverse through key2 and get the value of c, I can do a DFS on c's children to find the needed value.

This wont help if I specify a sibling key:value pair as one level of nesting. It needs an XPath like traversal. Say for the above case, my expression would be:

```
(a:1>>c)->{d:1}
(a:2>>c::d)->0
(key2::a)->[1,2,3]
```

Where :: is a child notation and >> is a sibling notation. 
Is there a simple or elegant way of approaching this? Are there libraries like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4372073/traversing-and-modifying-a-tree-like-list-of-dict-structure) for java to solve this?

Comment: Try: https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.jayway.jsonpath/json-path/2.2.0 (https://github.com/jayway/JsonPath) it's easy to specify a path into JSON object.

Answer (score 1):

You could tackle these sorts of problems using Java 8 library [Dynamics](https://github.com/alexheretic/dynamics). It allows you to traverse nested structures in a direct yet fluent & null-safe way.

```
Map nestedStructure = ...
// {key1=value, key2=[{a=1, c={d=1}}, {a=2, c={d=0}}, {a=3, c={d=1}}]}
Dynamic data = Dynamic.from(nestedStructure);

// "(a:1>>c)": all "c" values that have sibling "a" = 1
List<Map> aIs1CValues = data.allChildren()
    // filter to elements that have an 'a=3' child & a "c" map child
    .filter(el -> el.get("a").maybe().as(Integer.class).orElse(0) == 1)
    .filter(el -> el.get("c").isMap())
    .map(el -> el.get("c").asMap())
    .collect(toList()); // [{d=1}]

// "(a:2>>c::d)": all "d" values, with parent key "c" that has sibling "a" = 2
List<Integer> aIs2DValues = data.allChildren()
    .filter(el -> el.get("a").maybe().as(Integer.class).orElse(0) == 2)
    .filter(el -> el.dget("c.d").is(Integer.class))
    .map(el -> el.dget("c.d").as(Integer.class))
    .collect(toList()); // [0]

// "(key2::a)": all "a" values, with some parent key "key2"
List<Integer> key2As = data.allChildren()
    .filter(el -> el.key().asObject().equals("key2"))
    .flatMap(Dynamic::children)
    .filter(key2Map -> key2Map.get("a").is(Integer.class))
    .map(key2Map -> key2Map.get("a").as(Integer.class))
    .collect(toList()); // [1, 2, 3]
```

I wasn't totally sure about your real problem versus your example, this handling can be simpler if we know more about the data. For example, the last problem is easier if we know **key2** is top level and **a** is always present and an integer.

```
data.get("key2").children()
    .map(child -> child.get("a").as(Integer.class))
    .collect(toList()); // [1, 2, 3]
```

See https://github.com/alexheretic/dynamics for source, documentation and examples.